# Pass array in request payload in post request using backbone.js .save() method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to pass array in request payload to POST API call in BACKBONE. I tried passing array in save() but it is not going the way it is expected to be. The response I get from server is "Bad request. Expected an array".
The array is expected to go as:
["a","b"]
0:"a"
1:"b"
With my code it is going as :
{0:"a",1:"b"}
0:"a"
1:"b"
Here is the js code I tried:

```
var PolicyGroupMembers = Backbone.Model.extend({
    id1:"",
    url: function(){
        var url1= "http://localhostIP:9292/api/policy_groups/" +this.id1 +"/members";
        return url1;
    },
    // Before calling the save() function configure request 
    configRequest:function(options) {       
        this.id1 = options.id1; 
});
var systemGroup5 = new PolicyGroupMembers();
systemGroup5.configRequest({
    id1: "Ppj--v4UT1-NwrZ7PQkgOg"
});
systemGroup5.save(["a","b"]);
```

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27051113/4116375

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you would have to do something like

```
systemGroup5.save({0:["a","b"]});
```

from Backbone's annotated source

```
    if (key == null || typeof key === 'object') {
      attrs = key;
      options = val;
    } 
     else {
      (attrs = {})[key] = val;
    }
```

so a key value pair being expected

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I tried this, but the array is still not passing as expected.
Request payload I got using your suggestion is: 
{0:["a","b"]}
0: ["a","b"]

Comment: i added the 0 but this should be the key you are expecting, something like aArray if you are not passing the correct key you will get the same error

Answer (score 0):

To send array as expected, I overridden the default contentType (application/json) to application/text.
Following code worked:

```
systemGroup5.save({
    data: ["a","b"],
    contentType: 'application/text'
});
```